# Cannot use images in AWS Amplify when using Basic React App

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to host a React app in AWS Amplify while using images.

I used `create-react-app` to generate a project and pushed it into Github. Then, I deployed it into AWS Amplify and it works fine (images appear in the app such as './logo.svg' from create-react-app).

However, if I swap out the default SVG with my own image (any generic png), then push my changes to github (which deploys changes to Amplify), the image cannot be found in the app and displays as the alt text. I know for a fact my code works fine because locally I can use `npm start` and see my new image as expected. For some reason, images cannot be found in AWS Amplify once deployed.

Here is my amplify app at the time of writing: *https://master.d2xzaf0ph9z41j.amplifyapp.com/*

*EDIT* - adding file structure

```
my-app/
  README.md
  node_modules/
  package.json
  public/
    index.html
    favicon.ico
  src/
    App.css
    App.js
    App.test.js
    index.css
    index.js
    logo.svg
    new-img.png
```

EDIT2: Adding how the image is used:

```
import imgExample from './imgExample.JPG';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={imgExample} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        //more generic code
```

Comment: Can you post your code and the structure of your files here?

Comment: @Obed I added the structure which is created by ```create-react-app``` command. So for instance, if I place an image inside the src folder, say `img.png` and then I reference that from `App.js` , then Amplify does not find the new image after the deploy. I only see the alt text in place of the image on my site.

Comment: can you add how you are actually attaching the image?

Comment: I am using the ```create-react-app``` exactly as it is generated, except switching the stock svg with my own image. see my second edit above.

Comment: Looking at your site it seems you solved this. I am struggling with this as well... any clues would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this as well. For me I was using git-lfs and as it turns out the default build image used by AWS Amplify does not install git-lfs. The early indications were, from the browser's network debugger, I could see a file being successfully retrieved; however, it was far to small to be the image I wanted.

My solution was to create a custom build image which AWS Amplify will use to build my website. The steps on how I went about this and a link to the build image I used are in [github](https://github.com/wparkermackenzie/207south/tree/main/deploy/awsamplify).